# Concatenating 2 csv into 1 using pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

// I am trying to concatenate my 2 csv files into pandas data frame but I am not getting proper output 1st csv contains only 3 columns named  ProductID   ProductName ProductBrand and 2 nd csv contains this columns Price (INR) NumImages   ID  Description where instead of data I am  getting Nan I am getting data in my 2nd csv only after data of my 1 st csv is getting finished I am new to this Any help would be highly appreciated I am sharing my code too

```
// output:


    ProductID   ProductName ProductBrand    Gender  Price (INR) NumImages   ID  Description PrimaryColor
    10017413.0  DKNY Unisex Black   DKNY    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
    10016283.0  EthnoVogue Women    EthnoVogue  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

// Python Code:

import pandas as pd

# merging two csv files
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, ['data1.csv', 'data2.csv']), ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add axis=1 as below.

```
df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, ['a.csv', 'b.csv']), ignore_index=True, axis = 1)
```

Comment: this is working but column name is getting saved as 0 , 1, 2

Comment: Set 'ignore_index = False'. This should give you what  you wanted.

Comment: duplicate_cols = df.columns[df.columns.duplicated()]
df.drop(columns=duplicate_cols, inplace=True)
print(df)  i have been using code to remove duplicate columns but this is not working please help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is your mapping that is not working properly. I suggest 2 ways:

Given your `.csv` list: `csv_list = ['data1.csv', 'data2.csv']`

Using `map`:

```
df_mapper = map(lambda f: pd.read_csv(f), csv_list)
df = pd.concat(list(df_mapper), ignore_index=True)
```

Using list comprehension:

```
df_list = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in csv_list]
df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
```